# Opening external URL in new webview view controller

Tags: ios, url, webview

I have a webview application which works fine in loading my website. What I want to achieve is have it determine if a url tapped belongs to my site or not. If not have it open a new view controller.

I know I have to do something with this.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
```

But I don't know the best way to do it. From what I have searched, it only shows how to load a url in a webview (no issues there), or launch safari (not what I want).

Any info or guidance would be appreciated.

UPDATE 8/26:

```
//Download manager
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)awebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        #define kHostName @"http://www.mysite.com"
        NSString *host = [[request URL] host];
        if ([host isEqualToString:kHostName])
            return YES;
        else
        {
            WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
            [vc release];
            return NO;
        }


        //External file links
        NSURL *externalURL = [request URL];
        NSString *externalFileExtension = [[externalURL absoluteString] pathExtension];

        //External file extensions
        NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", externalFileExtension);
        if ([externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"zip"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"deb"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"rar"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mp3"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"pdf"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"exe"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mp4"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"flv"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"torrent"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"aiff"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"css"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"doc"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gz"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"hqx"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"htm"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"html"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ico"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ipa"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mov"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mpg"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ppt"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ps"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ram"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"rtf"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"swf"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"tar"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"tiff"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"txt"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"viv"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"wav"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"wmv"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"xml"] || [externalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ipsw"]) {



            NSError *error = nil; //error setting
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
            NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];

            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

            //Download manager
            HCDownloadViewController *dlvc = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
            [dlvc downloadURL:externalURL userInfo:nil];

            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dlvc animated:YES];
            dlvc.delegate = self;

        }else{

            //Internal file links
            NSURL *internalURl = [request URL];
            NSString *internalFileExtension = [internalURl pathExtension];

            //Internal file extensions
            NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", internalFileExtension);
            if ([internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"zip"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"deb"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"rar"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mp3"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"pdf"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"exe"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mp4"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"flv"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"torrent"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"aiff"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"css"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"doc"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gz"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"hqx"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"htm"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"html"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ico"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ipa"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mov"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"mpg"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ppt"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ps"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ram"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"rtf"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"swf"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"tar"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"tiff"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"txt"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"viv"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"wav"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"wmv"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"xml"] || [internalFileExtension hasSuffix:@"ipsw"]) {


                NSError *error = nil; //error setting
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
                NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];

                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

                //Download manager
                HCDownloadViewController *dlvc = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
                [dlvc downloadURL:internalURl userInfo:nil];

                [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
                self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:dlvc animated:YES];
                dlvc.delegate = self;

            }else{

///////////////
//IMAGE CODE///
///////////////
                //Image file links
                NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
                NSString *imageFileExtension = [[imageURl absoluteString] pathExtension];


                //Image file extensions
                NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
                if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"bmp"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"raw"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"PNG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPEG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"GIF"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"BMP"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"RAW"]) {

                    [webView stopLoading];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                    //Image manager
                    WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                    [vc release];

                }else{

                    //Image file links
                    NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
                    NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl pathExtension];

                    //Image file extensions
                    NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
                if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"bmp"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"raw"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"PNG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPEG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"GIF"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"BMP"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"RAW"]) {                        

                    [webView stopLoading];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                    //Image manager
                    WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                    [vc release];

                    }else{

                    //Image file links
                    NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
                    NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl absoluteString];

                    //Image file extensions
                    NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
                if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"bmp"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"raw"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"PNG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPEG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"GIF"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"BMP"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"RAW"]) {                            

                    [webView stopLoading];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                    //Image manager
                    WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                    [vc release];

                    return NO;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in the method you mentioned

```
[[request URL] absoluteString]
```

You could try using hasPrefix:(NSString*)prefix to check if url starts with the name of your site.

```
[[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"http://www.yoursite.com"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `host` and return `YES` if it's your own domain, or return `NO` if not, and then manually open new view controller:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        NSString *host = [[request URL] host];
        if ([host isEqualToString:kHostName])
            return YES;
        else
        {
            ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];
            controller.url = request.URL;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Clearly, tweak this to use `presentViewController` if you want to do a modal presentation. Likewise, replace `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` with `[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` (or whatever) if using NIBs. And my view controller has a public property, `NSURL *url`, but you would use whatever property you want. But hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: Will try this out. Only thing is I'm not using IB, it's all code. I will post all of my shouldStartLoadWithRequest to help with any further assistance.

Comment: @ChrisOSX That's fine. Just instantiate your view controller via code, like you normally would, set the property for the url you want that controller to open, and then transition to it (via `presentViewController` or `pushViewController`, as appropriate). But the idea is the same: check host, if yours, do your existing code, if not, do a permutation of the above code.

Comment: No matter how i try to configure this, it seems to open all links in my custom view controller. This"kHostName" throws  error also. Wants me to change it to "kCFHostNames".

Comment: @ChrisOSX In my code snippet, I assumed that you would define some constant, `kHostName`, and set it with the name of your host. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Gotcha. Ok I defined that. Yet urls belonging to my site push my custom vc, yet sites like dropbox for example still open in the webview. Updated OP with my current code, as it has changed a lot since my initial question.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, the WebImageViewController is just a test view controller, until/if I get this working properly.

Comment: @ChrisOSX You should `NSLog` the `host` variable and I think you'll find it does _not_ include the `@"http"`. Frankly, depending upon how your web server is set up, it could either be `"@www.mysite.com"` or just `@"mysite.com". Log the variable, and you'll see which you're getting, and then change your `kHostName` constant accordingly.

Comment: I'm using NSLog(@"url is: %@", host); This is what prints.

2013-08-26 21:07:29.988 MyApp[10456:cxx] url is: mysite.com
2013-08-26 21:07:33.630 MyApp[10456:cxx] didFinish: http://mysite.com/topic/; stillLoading:YES
2013-08-26 21:07:36.717 MyApp[10456:cxx] didFinish: https://www.dropbox.com/m/login?cont=https://www.dropbox.com/m; stillLoading:YES...I did take your above advice and changed my kHostName, so now it wont open my own sites link in the new vc, but still wont pass dropbox, youtube links.